# Better way to show that you have activate your filters

Tags: website-design, filter, ux-integration

What do you think is the best solution to show an active filter in my case? Do you have any other recommendation or thoughts?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think people have learned about green checkmarks versus forbidden/deactivated symbols, so you might use that as an indicator:

[image: Filter with icon]

The meaning of checkboxes to enable and disable things would probably work as well, too:

[image: Filter with checkbox]

If you don't like two icons on one button, you could also integrate the meaning in the filter icon itself:

[image: Filter icon modified]

Do not solely rely on red/green color. The shape should also change, so that people with red-green blindness have a chance to notice the difference.